# Error in compilation : cannot find symbol , variable treeView

Tags: java, javafx

I have copied i have copied a code from the internet in my project and , i have this issue :

> Error java: cannot find symbol 
>   symbol : variable treeView 
>   location: class homme.Controller

The Errors are in the second and third line :

```
final TreeItem<User> root = new RecursiveTreeItem<User>(users, RecursiveTreeObject::getChildren);
    treeView.getColumns().setAll(nameCol,ageCol,deptName);
    treeView.setRoot(root);
    treeView.setShowRoot(false);
```

and here is the all code of the controller :

```
    package home;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;



import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTreeTableColumn;

import com.jfoenix.controls.datamodels.treetable.RecursiveTreeObject;

import java.net.URL;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTreeTableView;

import com.jfoenix.controls.RecursiveTreeItem;

import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;

import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;

import javafx.util.Callback;


public class Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML
private VBox pnItems = null;
@FXML
private Button btnOverview;

@FXML
private Button btnOrders;

@FXML
private Button btnCustomers;

@FXML
private Button btnMenus;

@FXML
private Button btnPackages;

@FXML
private Button btnSettings;

@FXML
private Button btnSignout;

@FXML
private Pane pnlCustomer;

@FXML
private Pane pnlOrders;

@FXML
private Pane pnlOverview;

@FXML
private Pane pnlMenus;

@FXML
private JFXTreeTableView<?> treeView;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    JFXTreeTableColumn<User, String> deptName = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("Department");
    deptName.setPrefWidth(150);
    deptName.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<User, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<User, String> param) {
            return param.getValue().getValue().department;
        }
    });

    JFXTreeTableColumn<User, String> ageCol = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("Age");
    ageCol.setPrefWidth(150);
    ageCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<User, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<User, String> param) {
            return param.getValue().getValue().age;
        }
    });

    JFXTreeTableColumn<User, String> nameCol = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("Name");
    nameCol.setPrefWidth(150);
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<User, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<User, String> param) {
            return param.getValue().getValue().userName;
        }
    });

    ObservableList<User> users = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    users.add(new User("Computer Department", "23", "CD 1"));
    users.add(new User("Sales Department", "22", "Employee 1"));
    users.add(new User("Sales Department", "22", "Employee 2"));
    users.add(new User("Sales Department", "25", "Employee 4"));
    users.add(new User("Sales Department", "25", "Employee 5"));
    users.add(new User("IT Department", "42", "ID 2"));
    users.add(new User("HR Department", "22", "HR 1"));
    users.add(new User("HR Department", "22", "HR 2"));

    final TreeItem<User> root = new RecursiveTreeItem<User>(users, RecursiveTreeObject::getChildren);
    treeView.getColumns().setAll(nameCol,ageCol,deptName);
    treeView.setRoot(root);
    treeView.setShowRoot(false);

}

@FXML
private void filter(ActionEvent event) {
}

class User extends RecursiveTreeObject<User> {

    StringProperty userName;
    StringProperty age;
    StringProperty department;

    public User(String department, String age, String userName) {
        this.department = new SimpleStringProperty(department);
        this.userName = new SimpleStringProperty(userName);
        this.age = new SimpleStringProperty(age);
    }

}



public void handleClicks(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if (actionEvent.getSource() == btnCustomers) {
        pnlCustomer.setStyle("-fx-background-color : #1620A1");
        pnlCustomer.toFront();
    }
    if (actionEvent.getSource() == btnMenus) {
        pnlMenus.setStyle("-fx-background-color : #53639F");
        pnlMenus.toFront();
    }
    if (actionEvent.getSource() == btnOverview) {
        pnlOverview.setStyle("-fx-background-color : #02030A");
        pnlOverview.toFront();
    }
    if(actionEvent.getSource()==btnOrders)
    {
        pnlOrders.setStyle("-fx-background-color : #464F67");
        pnlOrders.toFront();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the creation of 'treeView ' object ?
You can not use it before creating it.

Comment: i have created this object as you can see in the fxml declaration :
@FXML
private JFXTreeTableView<?> treeView;

Comment: this statement :  private JFXTreeTableView<?> treeView; is declaration of object but its initialization  is missing

Comment: so can you suggest me a solution ?

Comment: Add treeView = new JFXTreeTableView<>(); 

before treeView.getColumns().setAll(nameCol,ageCol,deptName); 
Hope this help

Comment: okay thank you very much :)

Comment: you're welcome!